# jquery Separate list output with commas

Tags: jquery, csv

I cannot get this to output in a list separated by commas. the output is simply 444064451244515. I need it to be 44406,44512,44515

```
<?php
// return zip codes within a given radius of a given zip code
// TO DO - validate POST values

if(isset($_POST['findzip'])) {
    $myzip = $_POST['myzip'];
    $radius = $_POST['radius'];
    $api_key = $modx->getOption('zipcode_api');

    $url = "https://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/$api_key/radius.json/$myzip/$radius/mile";

    // cURL stuff
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $response = utf8_encode($response);

    $zips = $modx->fromJson($response);

        foreach ($zips['zip_codes'] as $zip) {
        $output .= $zip['zip_code'].split(",");
    }

    return $output;
}

return;
```

Comment: what is your input format ?? please provide sample input data

Comment: Use `.join(',')` for list separated by commas.

Comment: instead of the foreach just use $output = implode(",", $zips['zip_codes']);

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments above, something like this should work:

```
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['findzip'])) {
    $myzip = $_POST['myzip'];
    $radius = $_POST['radius'];
    $api_key = $modx->getOption('zipcode_api');

    $url = "https://zipcodedistanceapi.redline13.com/rest/$api_key/radius.json/$myzip/$radius/mile";

    // cURL stuff
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);

    $response = utf8_encode($response);

    $zips = $modx->fromJson($response);

    return implode(',', $zips);
}
```